# Change column value if it does not contain any of the given values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have CSV file and I am using Pandas to manipulate it. For example, I am checking if a column contains any of the values in an array, and if it does I change the value...

```
searchfor = ['LANGUAGES', 'FRENCH']
data.loc[data['field'].str.contains('|'.join(searchfor), na=False), 'field'] = 16
```

Now what if I want to do the opposite? If the array does not contain any of the values in the array, change it. So if a column value, is not `Languages`, nor `FRENCH`, change it to an `int`. I need a scalable answer as the array I am using could be very big.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use '~' operator for Not in.

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'field': ['LANGUAGES', 'FRENCH', 'BLAH', None, np.nan, 'Languages']})

searchfor = ['LANGUAGES', 'FRENCH']

data = data.loc[~data['field'].str.contains('|'.join(searchfor), na=False), 'field'] = 16
```

You get

```
    field
0   LANGUAGES
1   FRENCH
2   16
3   16
4   16
5   16
```

Do note that this code doesn't handle case, for that use str.upper() first

```
data = data.loc[~data['field'].str.upper().str.contains('|'.join(searchfor), na=False), 'field'] = 16

    field
0   LANGUAGES
1   FRENCH
2   16
3   16
4   16
5   Languages
```

Answer (score 1):

Negate the boolean indexer with a tilde (~):

```
data.loc[~data['field'].str.contains('|'.join(searchfor), na=False), 'field'] = 16
```